# mapping immutable properties using hibernate

Tags: hibernate

i am trying to map an immutable property with underlying DB using hibernate and here is the mapping file snapshot for the same

```
<hibernate-mapping default-access="field">    
<!-- Immutable property -->
            <property name="creationDate" column="CREATIONDATE" type="timestamp"
                update="false" not-null="true" />
```

i have not declared any property with the name creationDate in my class and hibernate is complaining me with the following error

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1341)
    at com.raisonne.tr.persistence.HibernateSessionFactory.rebuildSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:161)
    at com.raisonne.tr.persistence.HibernateSessionFactory.<clinit>(HibernateSessionFactory.java:72)
    at com.raisonne.tr.dao.impl.GenericDAOImpl.makePersistance(GenericDAOImpl.java:173)
    at com.raisonne.tr.service.impex.impl.DestinationImportServiceImpl.startDestinationImport(DestinationImportServiceImpl.java:130)
    at com.raisonne.tr.backoffice.actions.impex.DestinationImportAction.destinationImport(DestinationImportAction.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: field [creationDate] not found on com.tr.category.Category
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getGetter(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertyGetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:78)
```

i was following Hibernate's caveatemptor application i even  unable to see any property with the name creationdate in the respected Class in caveatemptor (Especially for creatiodate).

i am just thinking how best we can map such properties using hiberntae.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't get it. You have creationDate in your database, but you don't have it in your Java?

Comment: @partenon yes what  i want is that when ever an entity is getting persist in to table it should have information when it was created and for that i don't see any reason to declare proprty in my java entity class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments from the question: I'd say that you should have a `private Date createdDate = new Date()` in your Java class, without a setter (only a getter). This way, you (and Hibernate) still have access to it, but consumers of this entity are not allowed to change this value.

But if you really don't want it in your Java class, then you just need to remove it from your mapping (and use your database features to populate this field, like triggers). This error is because you mapped the database column, but there's no such property in the Java class. Just removing it from your mapping should suppress the exception.

Comment: agree i am experimething somethng like this.Thanks for the pointer